# Field Calcuator to add percent using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

What might I go wrong here is that I am trying to add percent. I use the Field Calcualtor and it keeps getting an error.

I am opening the Table to add a field named Percent and then type this:

```
round([T_Acres]/207 * 100,0) + "%"
```

Comment: What type of field are you calculating?

Comment: T_Acres  it is a total acres that has decimals and want to round it off to no decimals and insert percent.

Comment: @Aaron  THe Field type for this T_Acress is string, 20 as length

Comment: AND it is a dBase Table file

Answer (score 5):

the percent symbol is not a valid value in a numeric field. If you want to **see** the percent symbol, you can right click on your field name, go to properties -> number fomat and choose percentage.

[image]

otherwise (not recommended) you need a text field,but then you need to convert your numeric values to string (assuming that T_Acres is numeric and using the Python parser (note that in VB, the concatenation operator is "&" ))

```
str(round(!T_Acres!/207 * 100,0)) + "%"
```

EDIT If T_Acres is string, you can't use it for calculation (this is one of the many reasons why i is not recommended to store it in a text field). So you could do:

```
str(round(float(!T_Acres!)/207*100,0)) + "%"
```

Comment: I Tried that and it still gave me an error..

Comment: Did you shift to the Python parser @PROBERT?

Comment: @Aaron  Yes I did.

Comment: What error is it giving you? Can you give a sample value of en exact value from T_Acres?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why radouxju's answer wouldn't work, assuming you're calculating it into a text field. It's unclear (at least to me) what the data type of the field you're calculating is.

I get that T_Acres is a text field. It really shouldn't be, but that's water under the bridge. To get past this problem, how about creating a new double field called something like dblAcres, or whatever fits your needs. Use Field Calculator to populate that with:

CDbl(T_Acres)

This assumes that T_Acres contains only text versions of numeric values, that is, you don't already have values like '34.2369%' in T_Acres. The % sign will mess you up; it's a text value, not numeric. You can get rid of that, but I don't feel like posting a bunch of different solutions without knowing how your data is structured.

Anyways, if you do get actual numeric values into a new field, use the formatting method radouxju showed. If this is for labeling purposes you do not need or want a % sign in the field value (and in fact can't do so if the field is numeric); that can be added in the label expression and will display if you set formatting if you don't add it.

If this doesn't work, you may want to post a subset of your data, because the methods here should work.

Comment: While I agree with you it should work, I decide to go back to re-do this time with the shapefile and set as a VBscript and that expression I type worked !